# How do I change the login URL using Tank auth?

Tags: codeigniter, tankauth

I have been looking around the Tank auth code to see how things are done, but it seems a little confusing to find out how to change the path of the default login.

I wanted to change it to `groups/login` or `users/sign_in`, but that wasn't an easy task. I'm wondering whether I should change that from the routing file or any other file.

Any idea how to get around with this little issue?

Comment: ok, I want to answer my own question, but with a little thing that I could do, which is changing the 2nd part of path. These login, register, log out...etc... are actually functions built in the tank auth in the auth.php file located in the controller. if you decided to change any function name, make sure to change its name in all files included in the tank auth library. I still need someone to answer the 1st part on how to change **/auth/** directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering whether I should change that from the routing file

Yes, that's exactly what [URI Routing](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html/) is for:

```
$route['your/desired/url'] = 'auth/login';
```

If you need to kill the old URL for some reason, you can set it to something empty:

```
$route['auth/login'] = FALSE;
```

---

Unfortunately, the Tank Auth login url is assumed to be `auth/login`, and there are several redirects that must be edited. I recommend adding a custom config setting to `config/tank_auth.php`:

```
$config['login_url'] = 'your/desired/url';
```

Then replace all occurrences of `redirect('/auth/login')` with:

```
redirect($this->config->item('login_url', 'tank_auth'));
```

in the `Auth` controller and anywhere else it appears.

Comment: Thanks @Madmartigan for the great answer. And this exactly where I thought it should. however, there is a little thing I still don't get it. when I change the **$route[]** as you explained above to something else, I have to disable the old url, but it keeps redirecting to the old one if I don't write it myself on. any idea how to deal with that?? or do I have to change all the redirect functions in the whole code?

Comment: I understand, see update. Yes, you have to change the redirects manually because the url is hard-coded. There are several ways to handle it, but this is the simplest.

Comment: Thanks @Madmartigan, it is a great solution. I will try it out and leave feedback in here if things go fine or not. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks @Madmartigan. it 100% works. I had to change the path for each url manually and things got work well.

Comment: I think there are some links you need to change too. I remember now doing the same thing when I used Tank Auth.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the name of the controller from 'Auth' to whatever you want? Seems the shortest route to me.

Comment: The problem is that you would also have to change every instance of the path/url `/auth` in the entire application. By using a route and a config item, you can change it to anything you want quickly by editing in only 2 places. If you ask me, the shortest route is to just leave it alone ;)

Comment: @Prolamge, I tried that as well, but didn't success. Changing 'Auth' alone doesn't make things work because that will redirect to different url name you choose, but with error "404 error page". I know that the solution is long, but gives you the full control on the urls